# Apache - Rewrite Rule confusion

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

```
Redirect 301 /resort.php/FOO/BAR http://www.sitename.com.com/index.php
RewriteRule ^/direct/(.*) /direct/$1 [QSA,L] # access non i18n files directly
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2}\/.*)        /$1 [QSA,L] #any language subdirectory should be left alone
RewriteRule ^/(.*\/$)               /en/$1index.php [QSA,L] #fix for links ending in /
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php)             /en/$1 [QSA,L]  #any php file with no language subdirectory redirects to the default language
```

What's the explanation for why the first Redirect 301 isn't going to the homepage? When I replace it with..

```
RewriteRule ^/resort.php(.*) http://www.sitename.com/index.php [R=301,L]
```

It starts working. I'm sure it's because I have a bunch of rules and it goes to one and jumps to the other but I'm kinda lost and maybe a guru could explain this more clearly.

My directory structure is like so:

```
/en/index.php
/direct/
```

There is no /index.php in the root, I'm redirecting it to en initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive is getting into a bun-fight with mod_rewrite. The latter is quite aggressive, and is probably over-writing the redirect HTTP header set on the response by the `Redirect` directive.

You've already found the solution - use a `RewriteRule` to perform the redirect. The [L] flag means "last rule - don't process any more", which is how you prevent the rules from interfering with each other.  The plain `Redirect` directive is just an easy way of achieving the simpler functionality of `RewriteRule`.

Comment: ah, i knew it was some sort of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule /resort.php/FOO/BAR http://www.sitename.com.com/index.php [R=P, L]
```

your rules arent jumping around, in fact, the L flag means LAST rule, so when one is triggered, the file stops being read.